# Shift up div and fade in on option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFLEG/) that I found.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<header>
    <ul class="sidenav">
        <li><h2><a data-region="nav-1" href="#"><span class="title">About</span></a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a data-region="nav-2" href="#"><span class="title">Services</span></a></h2></li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div id="nav-1" class="infozone z1"><p>Hello I'm box 1.</p></div>
<div id="nav-2" class="infozone z2"><p>Hello I'm box 2.</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.infozone{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    height:400px;
    width:800px;
    display:none;
}

.z1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.z2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.sidenav a').click(function(){
  $('.infozone').fadeOut(550);
  var region = $(this).attr('data-region');    
  $('#' + region).fadeIn(550);
})
```

What I'm trying to do is...

1. Instead of regular links, they will be < option >s
2. If a user chooses a certain option, the div that's related to that
   option will fade in while moving up 5px. If there was a div that
   faded in before, that div would fade out while moving down 5px.

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFe5g/). Unfortunately, the `div's` are not fading in/out, and on top of that, I'm not really sure how to add the "moving up/down" effect.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kFe5g/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding click event on option, which doesn't work that way. You need to listen to the change event of the select element.

Try:

```
$('#stateList').change(function(){
   var region =  $(this).find(':selected').data('region'); //get the data value of the selected option
  $('.state').fadeOut(550);
  $('#' + region).fadeIn(550);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6chf/)**

For your question on animating the margin you can use the callback of fadeOut to achieve this.

```
$('#stateList').change(function () {
    var region = $(this).find(':selected').data('region');
    var $visible = $('.state:visible');
    if ($visible.length) $visible.animate({
        'margin-top': '5px'
    }, 550).fadeOut(550, function () {

        $('#' + region).fadeIn(550).animate({
            'margin-top': '0px'
        }, 550);

    });
    else $('#' + region).fadeIn(550).animate({
        'margin-top': '0px'
    }, 550);


})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yy9W/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind event with `select` instead of `option`. Try this

```
$('#stateList').change(function () {
    var region = $(this).find(':selected').data('region');
    $('.state').fadeOut(550);
    $('#' + region).fadeIn(550);
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kFe5g/7/)

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/kFe5g/8/)

Try this

```
$('#stateList').change(function(){
  $('.state').fadeOut(550);
    var region = $("#stateList option:selected").data('region');
  $('#' + region).fadeIn(550);
})
```